# How to send hotkey when a program starts?

Tags: load, autohotkey, startup, hotkeys

I just can't find anywhere how to automatically send a hotkey when a program starts. These simple tries don't work at all:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class Notepad
Send abcd
Send !vw
return
```

or

```
ControlSend, Edit1, This is a line of text in the notepad window., Untitled
```

The script should be able to:

- wait for the program to load before executing
- execute when a new window of the same program launched
- but not do so with the already executed and still existing one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#Persistent
SetTimer, SendHotkey, 300
return

SendHotkey:
    If !WinExist("ahk_class Notepad")
        return  ; do nothing
    ; otherwise:
    SetTimer, SendHotkey, off
    WinActivate, ahk_class Notepad
    WinWaitActive, ahk_class Notepad
    Send abcd
    WinWaitClose, ahk_class Notepad
    SetTimer, SendHotkey, on ; repeat the action next time the program starts
return
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm#Examples

**EDIT:**

make it works every time a new window is launched, but the already opened ones won't get affect a second time:

```
#Persistent
SetTimer, SendHotkey, 300
return


SendHotkey:
    If !WinExist("ahk_class Notepad")
        return  ; do nothing
    ; otherwise:
    WinGet, Notepad_ID, list, ahk_class Notepad    ; Get ID list of all opened Notepad windows 
    Loop, %Notepad_ID%                             ; retrieves each ID from the list, one at a time
    {
        this_Notepad_ID := Notepad_ID%A_Index%     ; "A_Index" contains the number of the current loop iteration
        If !InStr(Notepad_IDs, this_Notepad_ID)    ; If the variable "Notepad_IDs" does not contain the current ID
        {
            WinActivate, ahk_id %this_Notepad_ID%  ; "ahk_id" is used to identify a window based on the windows unique ID
            WinWaitActive, ahk_id %this_Notepad_ID%
            Send abcd
            Notepad_IDs .= this_Notepad_ID ? this_Notepad_ID " " : ""   ; The dot is used to concatenate (join) the IDs into a single variable. See Operators in expressions
        }
    }
return
```

Comment: It is very closed. Can you make it works every time a new window is launched, but the already opened ones won't get affect a second time?

Comment: Is `300` the waiting time to execute? I set it to 1000 but `abcd` is sent immediately to Notepad. When I replace all Notepad to SALFRAME (the ahk_class of Writer), it doesn't work

Comment: 300 is the [period](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm#Parameters) (the timer's repeating time). Add `Sleep 1000` before WinActivate if you want to send the command with one second retard. I don't have the Writer program, so I cannot say what's wrong with ahk_class SALFRAME. Try using [Multiple Criteria](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm#multi) (e.g. ahk_exe or ahk_exe Path within the WinTitle/WinClass parameter) or [WinText](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGet.htm#Parameters) after it for narrowing down the search of the window(s).

Answer (score 1):

i did saw in your comment that you did want to do this `send abcd !ow` , but you can not [Send text] + [send Hotkey] on the same codeline,

It must be written seperate in two codelines,

And if you want to send text and send a hotkey if a program starts, then The Ahk Script must be something like this.

```
; [+ = Shift] [! = Alt] [^ = Ctrl] [# = Win] 
#SingleInstance force
Doloop=1
a=1
mode=1

while Doloop=1
{
#IfWinActive, ahk_class Notepad
{
if (a=1)
{
WinWaitActive, ahk_class Notepad
sleep 150 ;use this if WinWaitActive does need a litte bit more time. (WinActive-WinShowup)
sendinput, abcd
sleep 150
sendinput, !ow
a=0
}else{
sleep 150
IfWinNotActive, ahk_class Notepad
{
a=1
;WinWaitClose ;you can use this if you want, to wait until the [ahk_class Notepad] is closed.
}}}

} ; end Doloop

#if mode
esc::exitapp
#if
```

Comment: it almost works. Can it be made to work every time a program starts? At this point I have to launch it before launching the program, and it will quit after done

Comment: This is a litte bit tricky, i did reedit my answer, you can now every time run the program, and if it is activate, it will do the action, then it will wait until it is not active. so that you can run it again.

Comment: it works, but if I switch to another program (say Firefox) then switch back, it reapplies the command. Can it be made to apply only once for each existing window?

Comment: Without using the Title name's from each Notepad files that you start, **you can not do that in autohotkey,**  `ahk_class Notepad` is for meant for all Notepad files. and it is not possible to write a script with these commands `#IfWinActive`, `#IfWinNotActive`, `#IfWinExist` , `#IfWinNotExist` - you will need a command like WinGet, Notepad_ID

Comment: This is suggested in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48424654/3416774). Can you take a look at it and see where it fails with Writer? Thanks.

Comment: that is correct, that is the reason why i did not change my answer with that command, i do want to give that guy a little bit more time and a fair chance so that his answer will be accept.

Comment: Their new information still doesn't work with Writer, which this one can. I've tried to read the documentations, but it's still intimidated to me. Can you post the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try also this:

```
; DetectHiddenWindows On
Gui +LastFound
DllCall("RegisterShellHookWindow", UInt,WinExist())
MsgNum := DllCall( "RegisterWindowMessage", Str,"SHELLHOOK" )
OnMessage( MsgNum, "ShellMessage" )
return

ShellMessage( wParam,lParam ){
If ( wParam = 1 ) ;  1 means HSHELL_WINDOWCREATED
{           
    WinGetTitle, title, ahk_id %lParam%     
    If (title != "")
    {
        WinGetClass, class, ahk_id %lParam%
        If (class = "Notepad")
        {
            ; Sleep, 1000
            ; WinShow ahk_id %lParam%
            WinActivate, ahk_id %lParam%
            WinWaitActive, ahk_id %lParam%
            Send abcd
        }
    }
 }
}
```

https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/80644-how-to-hook-on-to-shell-to-receive-its-messages/

Comment: It only works with SALFRAME when the virtual desktop is switched forth and back (VirtuaWin is used)

Comment: Try my edited answer with `DetectHiddenWindows On` and `WinShow ahk_id %lParam%`.

Comment: Say there are three windows named 1, 2, and 3 launched in different times in the same order. Then it only works for 1; switching the desktop back and forth will keep the string be sent to 1. But if I close 1, then 2 is the next window to be received the string like that. Then if 2 is close then 3 is the one. Anyway, I think this is the problem of this particular program, and I can make a macro for that. Thank you so much for your effort.

Comment: I've downloaded and tested LibreOfficePortable_5.4.3_MultilingualStandard and VirtuaWinPortable_4.4_English. On my system (Win10) there is no such problem. Both codes of mine work flawlessly on every new created Writer window and without DetectHiddenWindows .

Comment: I don't know why either. I'm on Win 7 32 bit. I'll accept the top voted answer then

Answer (score 0):

```
Loop {
    WinWait, ahk_class Notepad
    WinWaitActive, ahk_class Notepad
    Send abcd
}
```

Send had nothing to do with hotkeys. A hotkey executes an action when you press certain keys. Commands like `Send` simply simulate keyboard input.

Comment: I open Notepad but it doesn't auto type `abcd` on it. Can I do something like `Send abcd !ow`?

Comment: Sorry, it works. It was me to put the script on my other script. But it just send the key over and over. I want it to send only one time when the program starts